# android: do something in certain time

Tags: android, scheduling

I was read almost all article that have same question in Stackoverflow and somewhere else but those made me confuse.

my problem: I want my App toast something in certain time to the user (like alarm clock App that start ring in certain time) as an example, I want my App 2 days and 10 hour latter show a toast. but, during this period every thing maybe happen like application close, phone will restart or Etc... and the App doesn't show any thing.

my question is: How can do something in certain time in android App?

So now what is the solution? can any one help me and give me a sample code plz?
thank you in advanced,

Comment: @ johnnylambabda, hi, you're wright and I'm sorry about that because I didn't know the SO rule. thank you for remind me.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

You can also find a tutorial [here.](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)  If you are scheduling a precise time, you might want to actually be conservative and wake yourself up a little early, then schedule a toast using a Timer for finer grained control.